# Cannot RDP in EC2 Windows instance after associating Elastic IP

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I am having the following issue. I have an Amazon EC2 Windows instance running just fine.
I can RDP into it, no problem.

I have just created an Elastic IP and associated to the instance and now I cannot RDP anymore via the Elastic IP. I did update my RDP connection with the new Elastic IP/DNS (tried both).

I have gone back and forth associating/deassociating the Elastic IP and the issue is persistent when the Elastic IP is on...

I even opened up all ports on the security groups just to make sure nothing was coming that way, but no luck.

Am I missing some basic configuration steps here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK, don't ask me why, but it seems that my home network had some funny things going on this morning... web was working no issue, but RDP stopped in the end for bot Elastic and non-elastic ip connection. For the record I asked a friend to RDP in my instances and he had no issues so I figured it was something local...

Rebooted the ADSL modem and now everything works fine...

Cannot beat bad luck...